# Why does iOS Status Bar collapses because of Blur Effect since iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

I encountered a strange problem since `iOS 15`: I have a `Blur Effect` on the `App's Root View`, which changes depending on the `scenePhase`.
This was working perfectly until iOS 15 got released. Now, whenever the `Blur Effect` is 0, the `Status Bar` of the App collapses and the `Navigation Bar` moves up and is no more interactable.

```swift
struct RootView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State private var blurRadius: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            OtherViews()
        }
        .blur(radius: blurRadius)
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newValue in updateBlurRadius(newValue) }
    }

     private func updateBlurRadius(_ scenePhase: ScenePhase) {
         switch scenePhase {
             case .active : withAnimation { blurRadius = 0 }
             case .inactive: withAnimation { blurRadius = 16 }
             case .background: withAnimation { blurRadius = 16 }
             @unknown default: print("Unknown Case")
        }
    }
}
```

This code worked fine for `iOS 14` and before. However, since `iOS 15`, the following bug appears:

[image: Bug Preview]

- The curious thing is, that when the `scenePhase` becomes `inactive`, the `Navigation Bar` instantly jumps into its proper spot. And as soon as the `scenePhase` becomes `active` again, it jumps back to the top behind the `Status Bar`.
- Also, when changing the `Blur Radius` for the `active` `scenePhase` to 0.001 instead of 0, everything works perfectly fine and the `Navigation Bar` does not jump behind the `Status Bar`.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this strange behavior when working with `Blur Effects`?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use some stack instead of `Group`?

Comment: You asked "Why", so we are not in Apple SwiftUI team(at least not me), so how could be possible for us to answer why! Maybe you need to ask how to fix the issue.

Comment: @swiftPunk Yes ok, the Question I have is how to fix this behaviour.

Comment: @Asperi I just replaced `Group` with `ZStack`, however this does not solve the problem. Also, inside the Group Object is an `if-else-statement`, not just a single View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this exact issue and was not able to find a fix, so I am now using this alternative implementation, which does pretty much the same thing:

```
ZStack {
    // View to be blurred goes here
    Rectangle()
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .foregroundStyle(.ultraThinMaterial)
        .opacity(/* Your condition */ ? 1 : 0)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2))
}
```

This will overlay a blurry rectangle over your view.
So in your case:

```
struct RootView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            OtherViews()
            Rectangle()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .foregroundStyle(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .opacity(scenePhase != .active ? 1 : 0)
                .animation(.easeInOut)
        }
    }
}
```

Because this solution uses the new materials it only works on iOS 15. You can use `if #available(iOS 15, *)` to provide two different implementations, on for iOS 15+ and one for iOS 14 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not confident that this solution is markedly better than others, I'll suggest it for consideration due to its simplicity.

**Previous**

```swift
.blur(someCondition ? 2.0 : 0.0)
```

**Hacky "fix"**

```swift
.blur(someCondition ? 2.0 : 0.0001)
```